# Relationship between zsh custom completion script and compsys/zstyle configuration

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I have written a simple completion script for a command `cheat` so that when using `cheat` at a prompt zsh will autocomplete arguments.
(obviously) this needed to be setup in a compinit / compsys compatible way:

file: `~/system/dev_resources/zsh_comp/_cheat`

```
#compdef cheat

[bulk of code...]

# make call into compsys to provide completion!
_describe 'values' comp_cands_arr
```

avail the script to zsh through `~/.zshrc`:

```
fpath=(~/system/dev_resources/zsh_comp $fpath)
autoload -U ~/system/dev_resources/zsh_comp/*(:t)
```

The completion script works fine - no problems.
Now I simply want to reference and configure this completion script through the `zstyle` builtin.
The *COMPLETION SYSTEM CONFIGURATION* section in zsh [compsys documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Completion-System-Configuration) tells us:

> When completion is attempted somewhere on the command line the completion system begins building the context [...]
>   The fields are always in the order
>   .
>      **:completion:function:completer:command:argument:tag**

and

> [completer] The completer currently active, the name of the function without the leading underscore and with other underscores converted to hyphens. A ‘completer’ is in overall control of how completion is to be performed;

My question is, is my zsh completion script `_cheat` considered a "completer" in the context string?  i.e. would this be correct/applicable?

```
:completion:function:cheat:command:argument:tag
                     ^^^^^
```

It seems to be applicable, but at the same time the `_cheat` script is not a formally defined as a shell function, its just a loose collection of commands...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `_cheat` file *does* define a function called `_cheat`. You can verify that by displaying the function's code (`echo $functions[_cheat]`). When a function is [autoloaded](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-autoload) from a file, the file contains the function's code, as if there was `_cheat () {` before the file content and `}` after the file content. (Zsh also supports “ksh-style” autoloading where the file must contain a function definition plus a call to the function itself.)

The magic first line [`#compdef`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Autoloaded-files) found in a file in `$fpath` when the completion system is initialized is equivalent to calling `compdef _cheat cheat` where `_cheat` is the name of the file (and autoloaded function) and `cheat` is the name of the command that this function is to be used for. The association is recorded in the `_comps` associative array (`$_comps[cheat]=_cheat`).

The `completer` field in the [`zstyle` context string](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Overview-2) is the name of the completion function with a leading underscore removed.

Comment: thanks Gilles! when I run `echo $functions[_cheat]` zsh gives `builtin autoload -XU`. If I run  `% declare -f _cheat` gives `_cheat () { # undefined .... builtin autoload -XUz }` reading your [autoload](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-autoload) link - it seems autoloaded functions are not defined until they are invoked (hence autoloading) - So then I invoke the function by getting zsh to do a completion . **then** run `echo $functions[_cheat]` and BAM!  function definition!

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the question

> is my zsh completion script _cheat considered a "completer" in the context string?

The answer seems to be **no**
If you use <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>,<kbd>h</kbd> to dump zsh's completion context

```
% cheat b                                                                                                                             
tags in context :completion::complete:cheat::
    values  (_describe _cheat)
```

You can see that zsh considers the third/completer position to belong to the completer "complete" and that `cheat` is assigned the fourth or `command` position.
Importantly this is the command `cheat` (the actual executable program) and not the completion function `_cheat`, the completion function `_cheat`
is a value as defined by zsh's `zstyle` builtin.